# Custom filtering of HBase table in Java

Tags: java, filter, hbase, comparator

I have several HBase tables. They are all keyed differently but every key has 32 bit integer owner ID as a part of the key. It offset differently for each table, but I do know these offsets.
Now, I am passed in a Collection of IDs and I need to dump data pertaining to the passed in owners to the file. I.e. I need to do something equivalent to the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE substr(key_field, offset, length) IN (...);
```

Trying to achieve that I have written something like this:

```
public class SubKeyComparator extends BinaryComparator {

    private Set<Integer> idSet;
    private int         idLength = 4;
    private int         idOffset = 0;

    // getters/setters are here

    @Override
    public int compareTo(byte[] value) {
        return idSet.contains(Bytes.toInt(value, offset, length))? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```

It appeared not working as intended.
It is actually not working at all. I am opening a table and when I am trying to get

```
ResultScanner scanner = htable.getScanner(scan);
```

It waits a bit and then throws an org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException showing a dozen of java.io.EOFExceptions at
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getRegionServerWithRetries(HConnectionManager.java:1231)

Attempts to find a solution on the web or understand what's wrong going through the HBase source code did not yield any significant results.
If I do not insert my filter into the scan object, everything works fine.

If someone knows what is wrong or have done something similar, your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are aware that even when you get this to work it would be highly inefficient - i.e. going through every line in the tables where the owner ID is not the leftmost part of the key

Comment: Yes, I do know it. Unfortunately, it still need to be done.

Answer (score 2):

It is first important to note you have implemented a Comparator, *not a filter*. If you really want a *filter* what you need to do is extend [org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.FilterBase](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FilterBase.html)

If you look into the HBase logs you might see something like the following:

```
2012-09-20 16:55:27,913 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.HbaseObjectWritable: Can't find class com.mycompany.project.MyCustomComparator
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.project.MyCustomComparator
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    {lines removed for brevity}
2012-09-20 16:55:27,913 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.HbaseObjectWritable: Error in readFields
java.io.IOException: Can't find class com.mycompany.project.MyCustomComparator
  at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.HbaseObjectWritable.readObject(HbaseObjectWritable.java:514)
    {lines removed for brevity}
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.project.MyCustomComparator
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    {lines removed for brevity}
  at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.HbaseObjectWritable.getClassByName(HbaseObjectWritable.java:549)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.HbaseObjectWritable.readObject(HbaseObjectWritable.java:511)
  ... 15 more
```

This is because the comparator class is not available in the classpath of the HBase server.

In either case the custom class needs to be compiled and deployed to all region servers (perhaps in a JAR) and added to the HBase classpath.

Comment: is it possible to bundle custom filters with a Job jar (i.e. the same jar that has my mapper, reducer, and main class)?